# Django how to add 2 or more filters

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, jinja2

How to add multiple filters in Django

```
{{ order.get_cart_total | add:500 | floatformat:2 }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add these in a "*chain*", where the output of the first filter is filtered again, so:

```
{{ order.get_cart_total|add:500|floatformat:2 }}
```

That being said, It might be better to add 500 to the result in the `get_cart_total` method of the `order`, or in another method. A template is normally used to specify how data is *rendered*, business logic is normally written in the models and in the views.